# MS Access Table After Update Event

Tags: ms-access

I have an Access table that I want to track changes to. I made a simple audit table with 3 fields: Order_ID, UserName and Audit_Date. I then built a macro on the After Update event of the first table. I tried to use CurrentUser to populate the UserName field, but the macro fails. I removed the SetField to CurrentUser and the macro works fine. I can't use VBA in this situation. Is there any way to populate the UserName field with the AfterUpdate macro? Thanks.

Comment: Why can't you use VBA? What is CurrentUser - a custom VBA function, a field?

Comment: Yes, CurrentUser is a VBA function to get the name of the current user.  Their database is a real mess.  They are entering data directly into a table right now and are not ready for any forms.

Answer (score 0):

To reliably pick up the current logged in machine and user you will need to create a short user-defined function in VBA.  After that you can call that function in your SQL code and triggers:

```
Dim oShell As Object

Public Function MyUserID() As String  'Run a shell command, returning the output as a string

    If oShell Is Nothing Then Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

    Set oExec = oShell.Exec("whoami")    'run the whoAmI   command
    Do While oExec.Status = 0   'Synchronize with completion of command
    Loop
    MyUserID = oExec.StdOut.Readall   'Return the result from stdout
End Function
```

Invoke this in your SQL as MyUserID().

Notice that you can execute many Windows Shell commands in this way, including those within "cmd" itself.

Comment: That's great.  Thanks Chris!  I just don't see a "run code" option in the table's after update trigger macro.  However, it looks like I can run a separate data macro (which will call your function) from the trigger macro.  Klunky, but it'll work.

Comment: You SHOULD be able to Set Field... Value=MyUserID() right up in the macro.  Public Functions are accessible anywhere in Access, including SQL.

Comment: So, I just had a chance to test this out myself and it worked like a champ.  SetField Name: Changed_By, Value: MyUserID()

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED

Thanks Chris - for some reason I couldn't get that to work. But I found this solution in an answer to a similar question and it works:

In the data macro

SetLocalVar

Name ChangedBy

Expression = Audit